# POST XMLHTTPRequest not passing parameters in properly

Tags: xml, post, parameters, xmlhttprequest, stripe-payments

I am trying to make a Stripe POST request using XMLHTTPRequests. My body is not being sent properly. I've tried a lot of alternatives and nothing seems to work. Why won't it recognize the parameter?

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer sk_test_keygoeshere');

xhr.onload = () => console.log(xhr.responseText);

let data = `{
"amount": 1000,
"currency": 'usd',
"payment_method_types": ['card'],
}`;

xhr.send(data);
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",
    "message": "Missing required param: amount.",
    "param": "amount",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should never use your Secret API key client-side. If you do, anyone can access it and then have full API access on your account. Stripe offers a pair of API keys for that reason. One is the Publishable API key `pk_test_123` and is used to make a subset of calls client-side such as collecting card details. The other one is the Secret API key, `sk_test_123` and that one is stored securely on your server where you'll make the majority of API requests such as creating a `PaymentIntent` (what your code is doing), a `Customer` or creating a `Refund`.

The code you are trying to write should run on your server. And you should be using one of Stripe's 7 official client libraries in your favourite server-side language as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/development/quickstart).

If you switch that way, you won't have to fix the code you shared. But it doesn't hurt to explain the problem too here since it gives a better understanding of Stripe's API overall.

Stripe's API *returns JSON* but as the input it doesn't support JSON. Instead, it expects the data to be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for the majority of the API. So right now, the JSON data you are sending is ignored and their server only see you hit `POST /v1/payment_intents` with no parameters.

What you'd need to do is switch the `Content-Type` of your request first. Then, you'd want to ensure you pass the parameters properly encoded either using a form or URL encoding those. And if you were to send nested parameters you'd have to use the bracket notation such as `shipping[address][line1]` for example.

Overall though this is still the wrong approach, and using Stripe's official libraries server-side is really what you want.